# Difference between one glue and two glues after each other

Tags: tex-core

Is there a difference between

```
A\hskip 1pt \hskip 0pt plus 1fil B
```

and

```
A\hskip 1pt plus 1fil B
```

?

Are these two glues the same in terms of spacing and (line-)breaking? Or do they just add up, as I assume?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For spacing and line breaking rules, two glue nodes are exactly the same as one glue except that the algorithms run a little slower. So, the distinction only matters if

- you do node processing with `\unskip` (or using luatex)
- when the absolute of one of the combined parts would be larger than `\maxdimen` (in which case you cannot specify the single glue without an error)
- when you parse the output of `\showbox` somehow.

Comment: That's a much better answer than mine. I didn't even think about points two and three. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the necrology, but would infinite glues change the situation? (i.e. is `\hskip 1fil \hskip 1pt Text \hskip -1fil` different from `\hskip 1fil Text \hskip -1fil`?)

Comment: @Bruno: that is illegal input. Reverting to valid input, `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil \hskip 1pt` and `\hskip 1pt plus 1fil` are indeed treated identical.

Comment: thank you for the clarification (I only really know the expansion processor).

Answer (score 3):

They are mostly the same. The difference comes if you put a `\unskip` before `B`. In the first case, there will be `1pt` of space between the A and B. In the second case, there will be no space.

Comment: I am not putting unskip there :) The source is exactly as above. (Well almost, as I create the nodes by hand in LuaTeX)